# Anacron fails to open folder cron.daily

Tags: linux, cron

Recently I switched from user-specific anacrontab ( using -t ) to the global-one. Now each day anacron drops me a message (email to root) that it failed to open the cron.daily folder:

```
Subject: Anacron job 'cron.daily' on myComputer
Message: run-parts: failed to open directory /etc/cron.daily: No such file or directory
```

The rsnapshot-jobs run normally, however the cron-related jobs dont.
Here my anacrontab `/etc/anacrontab`

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron
#
# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
# days to wait - delay in minutes - job-name - command to execute
1   5   cron.daily  run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7   10  cron.weekly run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly    15  cron.monthly    run-parts--report /etc/cron.monthly
1   5   rsnapshot.day   /usr/local/bin/doBackup.sh daily
7   30  rsnapshot.week  /usr/local/bin/doBackup.sh weekly
```

And here the output of `ls -rtl /etc | grep cron` to see the folder permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      722 Jul  3  2012 crontab
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Sep 11  2015 cron.hourly
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Sep 11  2015 cron.monthly
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Sep 11  2015 cron.weekly
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Jan 25 16:04 cron.daily
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      858 Mar 21 10:49 anacrontab
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Mar 21 10:57 cron.d
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root     4096 Mar 21 10:57 cron-apt
```

( I dont have enough reputation yet to create the tag 'anacron'. If you are about to remove this line, please as well add the tag 'anacron' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved. Please check the answer on "superuser"](https://superuser.com/questions/1056326/anacron-fails-to-open-folder-cron-daily-cron-weekly)

Not sure if I should delete the question on "serverfault"? At least I am not able to mark it as duplicate, sice I only can refer to other server-fault questions.